# Table width not working as expected on Firefox html

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, printing

I'm have been confused why the table th width on Firefox browser cannot be edited into smallest value, but when I use Chrome browser it works, I just want to separate the value of my td into three rows like the image below but in Firefox.

In chrome which is working

[image]

In  Firefox which is not working

[image]

Entire Html

```html
<section class="users-list-wrapper">

  <div class="users-list-table">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="card-body">

          <div class="table-responsive">

            <table class="table" name="table" id="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="9">
                    <div class="titles">
                      <h3>This is Header title <br style="line-height: 20%;">
                        <span class="header2"> SubHeader title</span>
                    </div>
                  </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="4" style="text-align: left;">
                    <span class="municipality">Header</span>
                  </th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="heads">
                  <th class="heads">No</th>
                  <th width="5%" class="heads">ID Number</th>
                  <th class="heads">Name</th>
                  <th width="2%" class="heads">Country</th>
                  <th class="heads">Data total</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody class="report-content">
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>1235</td>
                  <td>Jason</td>
                  <td width="10px;">PH-COVID-160203000-00010165</td>
                  <td class="lenss"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>1235</td>
                  <td>Jason</td>
                  <td>United States</td>
                  <td class="lenss"></td>
                </tr>

              </tbody>
            </table>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: can you edit the snippet I made into a [mcve] - there is a LOT of code for printing which seems not relevant to your problem?

Comment: @mplungjan but in firefox the width of my country is not the same in chrome

Comment: Try [wbr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr)

Comment: @mplungjan but let us suppose I have dynamic value I think I cant use wbr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [wbr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr) - you can do it dynamically

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr td")].forEach(td => {
  const text = td.textContent;
  if (text.length > 20 && text.indexOf("-") != -1) td.innerHTML = text.replace(/-/g, "<wbr/>-")
})
```

```html
<section class="users-list-wrapper">

  <div class="users-list-table">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="card-body">

          <div class="table-responsive">

            <table class="table" name="table" id="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="9">
                    <div class="titles">
                      <h3>This is Header title <br style="line-height: 20%;">
                        <span class="header2"> SubHeader title</span>
                    </div>
                  </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="4" style="text-align: left;">
                    <span class="municipality">Header</span>
                  </th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="heads">
                  <th class="heads">No</th>
                  <th width="5%" class="heads">ID Number</th>
                  <th class="heads">Name</th>
                  <th width="2%" class="heads">Country</th>
                  <th class="heads">Data total</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody class="report-content">
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>1235</td>
                  <td>Jason</td>
                  <td width="10px;">PH-COVID-160203000-00010165</td>
                  <td class="lenss"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>1235</td>
                  <td>Jason</td>
                  <td>United States</td>
                  <td class="lenss"></td>
                </tr>

              </tbody>
            </table>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Firefox:

[image]

Chrome:

[image]

To split on length of content you can use regex

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr td")].forEach(td => {
  const text = td.textContent;
  // if the text has dashes but no spaces
  if (text.length > 20 && text.indexOf(" ") == -1 && text.indexOf("-") != -1) {
    td.innerHTML = text.replace(/-/g, "<wbr/>-")
  } else if (text.length >= 10) { 
    // see if there are words > 10 
    td.innerHTML = text.replace(/(\w+)/, function(match, word, index) {
      return word.length<10 ? word : word.split(/(.{10})/).filter(O => O).join("<wbr/>-")
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<table class="table" name="table" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="9">
        <div class="titles">
          <h3>This is Header title <br style="line-height: 20%;">
            <span class="header2"> SubHeader title</span>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" style="text-align: left;">
        <span class="municipality">Header</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="heads">
      <th class="heads">No</th>
      <th width="5%" class="heads">ID Number</th>
      <th class="heads">Name</th>
      <th width="2%" class="heads">Country</th>
      <th class="heads">Data total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="report-content">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>1235</td>
      <td>Jason</td>
      <td>PH-COVID-160203000-00010165</td>
      <td class="lenss"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>1235longstring</td>
      <td>Jason</td>
      <td>United States</td>
      <td class="lenss"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but do you know how can I set only the width in just column country?  I think its affect the other td tbody and th above snippet thank you

Comment: how about without "-" data to replace for example in ID number I have 1235 and I want to replace those using wbr ang split into 2 columns, the output should 12  in first row and second row is 35 it is possible?

Comment: Yes it is. I do not quite know what you mean by columns. You would want to split and join with `</td><td>` if you wanted columns

Comment: I mean split into two row like the previous one, previously you have replace it if there's "-" in td to split but what if we only based on the length of the text?  , like the snippet above ID number 1235 and I want to separate 12 in the first row and the second is 35  do you know how to write it into javascript? Im been trying it already but it's not working please thank you in advance.

Comment: See second example

Comment: thank you! it works on numbers but  it's not works on string?

Comment: You say numbers I use numbers. Please be more clear in your specs. Example inputs and expected outputs please

Comment: yes, if I change the value likes this "helo" instead of "1235" in 1235 it works but in string like "helo" doesn't work, please

Comment: But why and WHEN would you want to change helo into he/lo ?

Comment: thanks for your response, it just a dummy word but actually I want to change the string and separate it into 2 rows for example like this word  "HelloWordwonderland" if the length is above 10 the length should separate into two rows "Helloworld" in the first row since it has 10 length and the remaining is in the second row and if don't use your  code above the width of my table automatically extend and the word "HelloWordwonderland" will fit in the td table , please thanks in advance

Comment: Ok, see the new code. It is quite complex since I did not want to split United States into United Sta/tes